# INSERT command denied to user

Tags: mysql

I wrote script for my brother that seamlessly execute on my server, and after moving to his throws this error :

`INSERT command denied TO user 'nemesisp_user'@'localhost' FOR TABLE 'rekrutacja'`

Although in cPanel is the only one user created (along with the installation of Joomla) and has all privileges i google some theards but nothing helped.

Comment: Have you looked at `GRANT` ?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=insert+command+denied+to+user

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

First do this:

```
USE nemesisp_joomla;
```

Then try using GRANT once you have selected the database:

```
GRANT INSERT ON nemesisp_joomla.rekrutacja TO 'nemesisp_user'@'localhost';
```

Comment: #1046 - No database selected , when i have only one database nemesisp_joomla

Comment: `USE nemesisp_joomla`

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TO 'nemesisp_user'@'localhost' USE nemesisp_joomla' at line 1

Comment: Check the EDIT. Sorry for not being more clear. You first need to run the `USE` command, then run the `GRANT` afterwards.

Comment: Now i got this : #1142 - GRANT command denied to user 'nemesisp'@'localhost' for table 'nemesisp_joomla'

Comment: Sorry again, should be the table name there not the DB name. Try it now.

Comment: There's still something wrong : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''rekrutacja' TO 'nemesisp_user'@'localhost'' at line 1

Comment: You may or may not need the quotes around 'rekrutacja'. If that isn't working then I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Without quotes i still got previous error : #1142 - GRANT command denied to user 'nemesisp'@'localhost' for table 'rekrutacja' , well thanks for your help anyway.